# How would I write this differently to make it compatible with MYSQL 5.7

Tags: plugin-development, mysql

There is an issue with using `unique => true` in defining an attribute as a primary key when using MYSQL 5.7.*.

```
protected function defineAttributes()
{
    return array(
        'eid' => array(AttributeType::Number, 'unique' => true, 'column' => ColumnType::PK) 
    );
}
```

According to my setting this error should not occur. Here is the error.

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1171 All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead
```

Here is the SQL executed.

```
system.db.CDbCommand.execute(CREATE TABLE `craft_venti_events` (
    `eid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT NULL,
    `eventid` INT(10) NULL,
    `startDate` datetime NULL,
    `endDate` datetime NULL,
    `allDay` INT(10) NULL,
    `repeat` INT(10) NULL,
    `rRule` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    `summary` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    `isrepeat` INT(10) NULL,
    `locale` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    `dateCreated` datetime NOT NULL,
    `dateUpdated` datetime NOT NULL,
    `uid` CHAR(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (eid)
) ENGINE=InnoDb DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci)
```

Comment: Can you enable devMode and look at the SQL that's being generated for that statement and share it?

Comment: I have updated the question with the sql.

Comment: If you remove `AttributeType::Number`, does that help?

Comment: If I remove AttributeType::Number I receive the same error.

Comment: Hrm... one last thing. Pretty sure `unique` is unnecessary here as primary keys are unique by definition. What happens if you remove it?

Comment: I still run into the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug as of [Craft 2.6.2931](https://craftcms.com/changelog#build2931) with the `ColumnType::PK` enum 
in a record's attribute type definition.

Pretty sure it'd be a bug in < MySQL 5.7 because it's invalid SQL syntax as well unless they're just more forgiving of it there.

This is a non-issue in the upcoming Craft 3 release (the concept of attributes no longer exists and plugins explicitly define their table schema create statements), but the workaround for Craft 2 until the bug is fixed is to not use a record here and manually create the table schema that you need by adding an `onBeforeInstall` method to your plugin.

Comment: So by using onBeforeInstall and setting up the table the Record will detect that it is already installed?

Comment: Probably not... you'd probably either have to not use a Record there or have that record override BasePlugin's createTable command and do some custom logic.

Comment: is the issue in the base record's createTable or the DbCommand's createTable?